# appending some string into a list in database using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i having a problem in appending some string into a list in database
please help me

here is my models.py

```
class friendList(models.TextField):
    myFriend = []
class friend(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    friends = friendList().myFriend
```

and this is view.py

```
def addfriend(request):
    try:
        user = request.session['user']
        if request.method == 'POST':
            friend.objects.filter(username = user.username)[0].friends.append(request.POST['user_name'])
        return HttpResponse("ok he/she is your friend now!!")
    except:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error':"you are not logged in"})
```

Comment: I think that all your friend instances ('friend' must be uppercase) are sharing class variable myFirned of fieldList class.

Comment: i used this     print friend.objects.filter(username = user.username)[0].friends  before return HttpResponse and it was ok but in my db it wont saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your models. Since a friend can have many friends, each of which is an object of type `Friend`, you can add a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to the same model:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    friends = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

*The convention in Python is to have InitialCaps (also called CamelCase) for class names*

Now, in your view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def addfriend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        the_user = Friend.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        the_friend = Friend.objects.get(username=request.POST['user_name'])
        the_user.friends_set.add(the_friend)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Friend added!')
        return redirect('/index')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'No friend selected!')
        return redirect('/index')
```

For `POST` requests, you should always redirect. Here I am using the [`redirect` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to redirect the user back to the index page (you can change the URL to redirect them to anywhere else).

Django provides a [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates) which I am using to display messages to the user; the documentation will show you how to add code to your templates to show the messages.

Finally, the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) is a way to make sure that a view is only accessible if a user is logged in. It is part of the built-in authentication framework.